# Link a tkinter button to seperate script

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I have a tkinter interface with a few entry widgets as inputs. Upon clicking a button I would like those inputs to be sent to a separate script to be processed and a value printed and potentially returned back to the button (I am looking at this for a dual accuracy assessment statistic)

This is a lower scale example of what I have so far and am looking to accomplish

Example Secondary Script: GUI_ConnectorScript

```
def calculate():
    global result

    result = int(entry.get())
    result += 1
    print result
```

Primary Script: GUI_ConnectorScript

```
from Tkinter import *
import GUI_ConnectorScript

background = "#A8A8A8"
master = Tk()


screen_width = master.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = master.winfo_screenheight()

width = int(screen_width*0.7)
height = int(screen_height*0.7)
size = "%sx%s"%(width,height)
master.geometry(size)
master.title("GIS Display")


text = Text(master, width = 80, height = 40, background = background)
text.pack(expand = TRUE, fill = BOTH)

entry = Entry(master, width=5).place(x=100,y=100)

button = Button(master, text="Calculate", command=GUI_ConnectorScript).place(x=500,y=500)


mainloop()
```

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile and have look around a lot for an answer. I have found examples similar but I am having an issue getting it to work for my application.

Comment: This is where you need Object-Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Parviz, whenever GUI programs get too complicated you should use Object-Oriented Programming.

I can further advice that you use kivy (if possible) instead of tkinter, its much better for bigger projects

Comment: I appreciate the advice to looking into using kivy. Until I understand it more, is there an example of what I cam trying to accomplish that you know of? I am new to using GUIs and an a solid example pulling your comments together would be great

Comment: Hi jake, Kivy's wepage is pretty complete, along with it there is a tutorial here: https://pythonprogramming.net/kivy-application-development-tutorial/ wich helped me alot,

Comment: @Cid-El actually, I'm pretty sure that the OP can accomplish this task using Tkinter, so no need to dig into new platform, I think, because IMO, the main problem here is about [modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) which is a fundamental concept. It does not require OOP (in fact, it can get done using structured programming in Python), but from a better design point of view, I would rather go with OOP.

Comment: @Jake I recommend you to start to read about [Modular Programming and Modules in Python](http://www.python-course.eu/modules_and_modular_programming.php). This should give you some basic understanding about what modularity is and how to make modules and use them.

Comment: @Parvis I only made a suggestion, whenever one wants to do GUI programming often Kivy is a better option than Tkinter IMO.